# How to pass parameters to a verilog module when performing synthesis?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, synthesis, register-transfer-level

I have a parameterized verilog module with a bitwidth that is variable depending on the value given in `define WIDTH.

However, I would like to be able to somehow change the value of WIDTH by passing in a parameter during synthesis using design compiler.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

For instance, I'd like to be able to write the following for my input file for design compiler:

```
analyze -format sverilog -define WIDTH 10 myverilogfile.v
```

Comment: That probably depends on your design compiler, refer to the user manual first.  One idea, if that functionality isn't built into the compiler, is to write a small script to substitute a keyword with a value, then run the analyze function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Design Compiler the format is:

```
analyze -format sverilog -define WIDTH=10,DEPTH=128 myverilogfile.v
```

Comment: What about if I am using parameterized modules? not a defines file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most compilers will let you do this.  It is tool-specific, though, there is no standard spec for this.  The most common format to do this would be `+define+WIDTH=10`; you would have to check the documentation or help for your compiler though (or experiment)